# Unable to access clients in CiviCase

Tags: civicase

I am using Wordpress 4.4.2 and recently upgraded Civicrm to 4.7.3

When I try to "manage" a case, that is, access the record itself, I get this message:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Unable to load configuration file for the referenced case type: 'My Case Type' (learn more...).

Answer (score 1):

That error is almost always related to name vs label mismatches. Check your xml files for the `<name>` tag and the entries in the database in civicrm_option_value in the "name" column, e.g.

`SELECT ov.name, ov.label FROM civicrm_option_value ov INNER JOIN civicrm_option_group og ON og.id = ov.option_group_id WHERE og.name='case_type'`

Answer (score 0):

Leslie, I am not getting that error.  However, CiviCase rights are not given to any user below WordPress administrators by default.  Is this WordPress account an Editor or below?  Check the Administer -> Users and Permissions -> Permissions -> WordPress Access Control and find the CiviCase section, about three quarters down the page.

Comment: GH, thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the delay in responding. All the users are administrators and so should have complete access to all the civicase functions. This problem only started with the update.